# Continuous and additive operator is linear

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be any normed linear space, $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous and additive. Show that $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y),$ i.e $T$ is linear and continuous.

This is what I reach so far:

Since $T$ is continuous and additive, i.e for any $x,y \in X$, $T(x+y)=Tx+Ty$, it suffices to show that for any $\alpha \in K$, with $K=\mathbb{R} $ or $K= \mathbb{C}$, $T(\alpha x)=\alpha Tx$. I have tried a prove by a contradiction, but it did not work since okay I have $\Vert T(\alpha x)-\alpha Tx\Vert>\epsilon$ for some $\alpha \in K$ and $x \in X$ by that does not help to find a contradiction.

I would appreciate any help or hint.

Thank you all.

Comment: From additivity and induction you can prove that $T(nx+my)=nT(x)+mT(y)$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$. Also $T(x)=T(q(x/q))=qT(x/q)$ for $q\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $T(\frac{1}{q}x)=\frac{1}{q}T(x)$. Putting them together you get that $T(r_1x+r_2y)=r_1T(x)+r_2T(y)$ for $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{Q}$. By continuity, you can take limits when those $r_1,r_2$ tend to arbitrary real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For a hint, you can prove that $T(rx) =rT(x) $ for rational $r$, then use continuity.

Comment: Slight intermediate hint for OP: prove it for natural $r$, then integer, then you can prove it for rational.